# Creating 2 Relationships Between Two Entities Using Entity Framework Code First

Tags: ef-code-first

I'm trying to define a one to many relationship, as well as a one to one relationship between the same 2 entities "UserProfile" and "Blog".  I think I have succeeded with the following code, however, it results in creating a new column in "Blog" table called "UserProfile_UserId" (FK).  I don't understand why it does this.

The relationships in English are: 
1. "A UserProfile has many Blogs"
2. "A UserProfile has one main optional (nullable) Blog"

So ultimately I'd like to see a FK from Blog.UserId to UserProfile.UserId
And a nullable FK from UserProfile.BlogId to Blog.Id
And I think that is all...  I especially don't want additional columns added by EF.

```
public class UserProfile
{
    [Key]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public int? BlogId { get; set; }
    public virtual Blog Blog { get; set; }  // This is a user's main blog
    public virtual ICollection<Blog> AllUsersBlogs { get; set; }
}

public abstract class Blog
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }


    public int UserId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("UserId")]
    public virtual UserProfile User { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's pretty tricky thing to make - by default CF puts all the relationships / FK-s on one side. And that's for a reason, because it simplifies things, avoid cyclical references and contradicting 'constraints' on two sides

> what often happens is the error reporting that from one FK ir requires
>   to be of multiplicity '1' and from the other FK it has to be `*` -
>   resulting in an exception.

But this works all you want I think - you just have to 'feed it' the data carefully...

```
public class UserProfile
{
    [Key]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Blog")]
    public int? BlogId { get; set; }
    public virtual Blog Blog { get; set; }  // This is a user's main blog
    public virtual ICollection<Blog> AllUsersBlogs { get; set; }
}

//abstract 
public class Blog
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("User")]
    public int UserId { get; set; }

    // [ForeignKey("UserId")]
    public virtual UserProfile User { get; set; }
}
```

In your fluent config...

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Blog>()
    .HasRequired(x => x.User)
    .WithMany(x => x.AllUsersBlogs)
    .HasForeignKey(x => x.UserId)
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

And use it like this...

```
var user = db.UserProfiles.Add(new UserProfile
{
    //Blog = mainblog,
    AllUsersBlogs = new List<Blog>
    {
        new Blog{},
        new Blog{},
        new Blog{},
        new Blog{},
        new Blog{},
    }
});
db.SaveChanges();
var mainblog = new Blog { User = user, };
user.Blog = mainblog;
db.SaveChanges();
```

Note that for the main blog - **you have to explicitly specify the `User` for your blog** now - plus set it as the user's main blog.

That's because you have two different relationships now - one is mandatory (User in the Blog) - and another is the optional main blog.

> Anyhow, if this doesn't satisfy your demands (though it looks it
>   should I think) - then I'd suggest that you let it create things by
>   default and have FK-s on the Blog side, you lose the BlogId but it
>   simplifies things a lot.

Comment: This looks like a solution.  I wish I could understand how you arrived here though.  One question: when you explicitly specify the user for the blog, cannot it not be new Blog { UserId = userId } or does it have to actually be the User model, and if so why?  I'm going to implement this soon and I'll report back.  Thanks!

Comment: as for the `UserId` - I didn't try but that works fine if mapped right (always check your migration script to see that it's mapped properly), fk is all you need. As for the `how`, well, there is no straight answer here, I wish I knew what it is to tell you. This is 'trouble' sort of (and as I explained) so you need to 'tweak' it, try manually, do migration and see the script, try few different things - just some experience, I know what works or doesn't (but no one liner).

Comment: This solution worked wonderfully.  I am concerned about the specific exactness and thus tricky nature of the solution, but I really don't see a better way.  Not sure if allowing EF to generate new FK's is really the better way to go here.

Comment: Just as an aside, I'm fairly new to EF and I used to always write and maintain SQL scripts for my data models.  It's exactly this sort of stuff that really make me second guess ORM's.  Specifically, it took me like a day to massage the data attributes and get a few tables keyed and FKed up properly.  (Not to mention the hackery like in this example.)  Should I maybe look at abandoning code first, or perhaps just use the Fluent API only?  Just asking the more experienced folks out there what their opinion is.  Thanks.

Comment: I don't think you should be concerned - this isn't as much a hack as working around some issues EF still has (eg the `ForeignKey` works better if on the fk-id, why, have no idea), it was much worse in the beginning. The rest is some db logic, if you think of your entities too much like classes you'll end up w/ issues - think of tables/fk-s (when designing). I'm a db guy myself (sort of, half/half), and had many db-first code generators written (and one ORM-like tool) etc. - but CF is a big save of time. For prototyping and for production (I started using it on most sides)...

Comment: be aware of issues and you'll be fine - you can go through some 'general posts' of mine (and others') on how to use CF in production (I don't have the links handy e.g. google 'NSGaga stackoverflow code first production' or similar). You can always mix things etc.

Comment: ...and if you still have issues just post a new question and `@` tag me here and I'll try to help :)

Comment: I appreciate the help.  It sounds like it's just a knowledge issue and I should give Code First more of a chance.  I have found that it is rather fast for prototyping (assuming I don't set up relationships properly, but rather just focus on the data.)  Maybe in time I'll gain enough knowledge to set up the relationships without too many annoying subtleties creeping up.